# Using Proguard on App Engine Connected Android Client

Tags: android, google-app-engine, proguard, requestfactory

I'm getting close to putting my app up on the Google Play store and I'm trying to obfuscate with Proguard. It uses GAE and the RequestFactory and I'm getting the 'RequestFactory Validation Tool must be run for...' exception. Seen a few posts on this, and a few answers but nothing definitive and nothing that works for me. I understand the reflection/symbolic issues and have excluded the RequestFactory interface from obfuscation but to no avail. Can someone provide a simplified working example of what should go into the proguard config file to get through this successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a description of what the RequestFactory Validation Tool does internally, but chances are that it has added annotations. ProGuard's obfuscation step removes those by default, but you can keep them:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Comment: I already had the line
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
which I took from another post. I added your suggestion as well but to no avail. 

This is the exception that's thrown

java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the com.client.MyRequestFactory RequestFactory type

Comment: I finally got it working I had understood that my derived MyRequestFactory interface should be excluded so had the option

              -keep interface com.myapp.client.** { *; }

MyRequestFactory is the only thing in the com.myapp.client package.

It still crashed. I then went back to reading about the validation tool. It generates a MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder class. Added the following

              -keep class com.myapp.client.** { *; }

And it started working. Too soon to celebrate though - I have a number of unexpected exceptions at other places in my app......

Answer (score 4):

May be late after an year.
Just this would help for someone using proguard for app engine,
**Add this to your proguard.cfg file**

```
# Needed to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version

-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version

-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**
```